# Interval and density forecast in R with both heteroskedasticity and non-normality in time-series data

Tags: r, forecasting, heteroscedasticity, prediction-interval, density-estimation

We tried to get both an interval and density forecast based on time-series data, which we found to be both non-normal and heteroskedastic, in R.

We know that for non-normality, forecasts can be achieved through bootstrapping procedure, by doing the following:

```
R=1000
OLS2 <- lm(y~x)
Resid <- OLS2$residuals
BootStrapDraws <- sample(Resid, R, replace = TRUE)
BootstrapForecast <- point + BootStrapDraws
DensityForecast_Bootstrap <- density(BootstrapForecast)
plot(DensityForecast_Bootstrap, main = "Density", xlab="y")
```

## Forming the interval forecast

```
lowerbound<-quantile(BootstrapForecast,probs=0.025)
upperbound<-quantile(BootstrapForecast,probs=0.975)
print(lowerbound)
print(upperbound)
```

For heteroskedastic disturbances, we can use a GARCH(1,1) model and get estimates of parameters omega, alpha and beta to get the volatility of the disturbances:

```
library(fGarch)
volt = diff(ln.as$ln.auto)
t.g <-garchFit(data = (volt)^2, cond.dist = "std", type = "h", trace=F, leverage=F, include.mean = F)
garch_coefficient <- coef(t.g)
coef(t.g)
h = volatility(t.g, type="h")
```

For 626 observations,

```
h_626 = print(garch_coefficient[1] + garch_coefficient[2] * (volt[625])^2 + garch_coefficient[3] * h[625])
h_626
sqrt(h_626) #sd  0.07417871 
h_1 = print(garch_coefficient[1] + garch_coefficient[2] * (volt)^2 + garch_coefficient[2] * h)
mean(h_1)
sqrt(mean(h_1))
```

## Interval

```
print(SE_sc)
SE_sc <- sqrt((length(volt)-1)/(length(volt)-2))*(sqrt(h_626))
interval_forecast <- c(point_prediction_sc - 1.96 * SE_sc, point_prediction_sc + 1.96 * SE_sc)  
interval_forecast
```

Density Forecast - having to deal with heteroskedasticity.

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
```

## Density Histogram

```
Dist <- rnorm(1000, 0, sqrt(h_626))  #Disturbance draws
Outcome <- point_prediction_sc + Dist
hist(Outcome, main = "Density Histogram")
```

## Density Plot

```
densityFig <- density(point_prediction_sc + Dist)
plot(densityFig, main = "Density Plot")
```

However, how do we get a single density forecast and interval forecast when computing both at the same time? Do we have to plug the residuals of GARCH(1,1) model in the bootstrapping procedure? We have no idea how to proceed, as this is the first time we're facing this problem.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: 1. please approve the edits that were made to your post. 2. Please attempt to provide both more context (not more code), and a clearer explanation of what  you are trying to do (treating it as a statistical question rather than a coding question).

Comment: both actions will tend to speed up the process